# Problemas al imprimir desde javaScipt, se imprime un String y no una sentencia HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, xhtml

Necesito imprimir una sentencia html desde javascript

```
{listaFestividad.obtenerLista("November 10")}
```

la cual al hacer de forma directa no me presenta ningún problema

```
append('#{listaFestividad.obtenerLista("November 10")}');
```

Pero necesito que el dato "November 10" vaya variando de acuerdo  a la fecha dada en un ***datapicker*** por lo que intente realizar esto:

```
append('"#{listaFestividad.obtenerLista("'+date+'")}"')
```

Pero me sale error de sintaxis.

Entonces opte por hacer un proceso de trabajar declarando variables que vayan construyendo el texto poco a poco.

```
var variableP='{listaFestividad.obtenerLista';

var ds='#'+variableP+'("'+fecha+'")}';

append(ds);
```

Lo cual no me presenta error pero no se visualiza la información que quiero mostrar se muestra como texto y no como una sentencia ***HTML*** también e ejecutado un ***alert*** que me ayude  `alert(ds)`, saliendome.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado el valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obteniendo el valor String que es el seleccionado pero yo quiero que se ejecute la sentencia mas se ejecuta esto como un valor String. podría convertir este valor para que sea interpretado como etiqueta html. el problema creo va por aquí

**[image: texto en negrita]**

En esta parte de código donde esta seleccionado esta variable podemos convertirla en sentencia HTML ya que me interpreta con un texto por favor ayuda.

Comment: y si usas [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)?

Comment: Con innerHTML el problema es el mismo quiero ver una forma de que la variable  ds se convierta a etiqueta HTML por que se comporta como un texto. Antes de hacer el append o InnerHTML puedo transformar esta variable a etiqueta HTML? alguna solucion                                                                                                var ds='#'+variableP+'("'+fecha+'")}';
append(ds);

Comment: La verdad es que no entiendo qué es lo que quieres hacer... En **HTML** como tal no existen las sentencias. Supongo que lo que quieres es devolver algo como "#variable(fechaDelInput)" en un alert, o lo que sea?

Comment: Quiero Devolver el valor generado  por ejemplo si coloco #variable(fechaDelInput) me deve salir la fecha como tal "16 Mayo" pero como digo me devuelve un String osea me devuelve como String esto [#variable(fechaDelInput)] texto como tal y no el valor  la pregunta seria  puedo esto transformar por  que me coje como string [ds='#'+variableP+'("'+fecha+'")}'] como transformo esto en una sentencia HTML??